# abap runtime error program line too long

Tags: runtime-error, abap

Good day. The programs function is to take an equipment number (or none), display that number with a description (or all) in alv, and then run IE03 should the user double click on

Program worked fine in client 110, but in 150 a runtime error happens. This morning I tried to make a new program with a shorter name (only lead I had), activated it (window popped up asking me to activate the previous version as well). That didn't work and now the original doesn't work in either.

The program "SAPLSKBH" is terminating because program line is too long, being 78 chars wide which is too much for the internal table "\FUNCTION=K_KKB_FIELDCAT_MERGE\DATA=L_ABAP_SOURCE[]"

Comment: This has been down-voted because you should try to be more specific which code you wrote (code sample is great) and what you were trying to accomplish. Also for us client 110 and 150 are meaningless, you could just say that it worked in 1 client and not in another. You should probably withdraw this question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY for output, is that correct?

Check you source code; somewhere you have a line that is more than 78 characters. The function K_KKB_FIELDCAT_MERGE takes the source code of your program to produce a structure that corresponds to the table/structure you give it. (In the old days, there was a limit of 78 characters width for a line of ABAP code, and this is an old function module).

You can alternatively build a field catalog yourself in code, rather than use this function.